# Регулярное выражение для поиска имени файла

Tags: php

В разметке страницы есть вставки с mp3-файлами следующего вида:

```
'link' => 'music_name_123.mp3'
```

Нужно при помощи регулярного выражения получить все имена файлов: `music_name_123.mp3`, при этом возможны варианты с пробелом и без него (и с любым количеством пробелов):

```
'link' => 'music_name_123.mp3'
'link'=>'music_name_123.mp3'
```

Помогите с написанием регулярного выражения. Работает все кроме определения пробелов:

```
link'[\s.*]=>[\s.*]'([a-zA-Z0-9].*.mp3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
link'\s*=>\s*'([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.mp3)
```

И в `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` укажите все символы допустимые в имени файла

Проверять выражения удобно онлайн: https://regex101.com/